# Facebook Like Link Sharing on Status Updates

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to implement a text box for link sharing but once I copy the link, I want it to show a thumbnail of the link like in facebook. Any ideas how to implement this ? Should I write a javascript to get the screenshot of the given link ? Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using HtmlAgilityPack to down load html and fetch the image url

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//link[@rel='image_src']");
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

that is done on the server, not possible only with JavaScript, unless you get some crazy activeX, etc., or you can try one of those thumbnail providers and use their API, http://snapcasa.com/

Comment: how do we do on the server side ? could you please explain the algorithm a bit ?

Comment: what server technology are you using? unless you have extremely high volume and lots of time or planning to sell it as a service, it will be much cheaper to pay per usage than develop it by yourself

Comment: .net but I want to know about it.